# What is this error that I'm capturing here, why does it show line, columns, for React Native app?

Tags: react-native, es6-promise

The code inside api.login(), when there is a and error like a network error, I get the following at the top layer, is this the right way to capture that? I'm beginning react native development, so unsure if there is anything else I should be improving, any help is appreciated, thank you!!

```
  loggedIn = await api.ping();
  const state = store.getState();
  if (!loggedIn) {
    try {
      await api.login(state.User.email, state.User.password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('GOT AN ERROR' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
  }
```

If there is no network connection it returns the following...:

```
GOT AN ERROR{"line":139075,"column":38,"sourceURL":"http://127.0.0.1:19001/node_modules/expo/AppEntry.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false&hot=false"}
```

The line inside api.login is a catch(error) as well that returns the following:

```
const login = (email: string, password: string): Promise<Object> =>
  axios
    .post('/sign_in', { email, password })
    .then(res => { ... })
    .catch(error) {   
     return Promise.reject(new Error(error));
   }
}
```

Am I doing this right? Why is that error just a hash with a line, column, etc?

Comment: I don't think you need the `new Error`... the error was already created via the catch. Just simply pass the error: `return Promise.reject(error);`